# Stoplight Spectral - using logical OR in rules via function

Tags: javascript, yaml, spectral

I want to achieve, that a rule fulfills two conditions connected with an or. I defined these conditions as functions.

How do I achieve this?

I tried to "import" the two functions into a third function which i then referenced in the rule, but js wont allow the import without defining a module

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

which spectral doesnt like... (after setting `<script type="module">` )

```
Unexpected token '<'
```

When i "require" the two functions "require" is not defined.

```
require is not defined
```

Comment: Did you mean `<script type="module">`?

Comment: yes - but spectral doesn't even like the script tag, fixed it in the question

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my spectral installation - after an update the "require" worked for me like expected.

Version working for me is:
Spectral: 5.6.0
Node: v14.13.0